# Sorting documents in Meteor.js collection causes browser to crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to retrieve the newest document from a collection which has a `timestamp` field. However when using the `sort` specifier with either `find()` or `findOne()`, the browser becomes very unresponsive, CPU usage shoots up and occasionally crashes.

The sorted result returned is also not sorted correctly when compared to a direct query on mongodb using `db.fruits.find().sort({timestamp: -1})`. An example of a value in the `timestamp` field is `2013-11-28 21:48:02`. There are 5000+ documents in `db.fruits` with an index on `timestamp`.

Any ideas what went wrong? I'm using Meteor v0.6.6.3 on Mac OSX Chrome.

**Case 1A: Responsive**

```
Template.fruits.fruit = function() {
    var fruit = Fruits.findOne({});
    return fruit;
}

<template name="fruits">
    <div>{{fruit.price}}</div>
</template>
```

**Case 1B: Unresponsive**

```
Template.fruits.fruit = function() {
    var fruit = Fruits.findOne({},{sort:{timestamp: -1}});
    return fruit;
}
```

**Case 2A: Responsive**

```
Template.fruits.fruit = function() {
    var fruit = Fruits.find({}, {limit :1});
    return fruit;
}

<template name="fruits">
    {{#each fruit}}
    <div>{{price}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

**Case 2B: Unresponsive**

```
Template.fruits.fruit = function() {
    var ticks = Ticks.find({}, {sort:{timestamp: -1}, limit :1});
    return fruit;
}
```

---

**Publishing only the newest 10 fruits**

*Suggested by David Weldon*

```
Meteor.publish('fruits', function(userId) {
    return Fruits.find({}, {sort:{timestamp: -1}, limit: 10});
});
```

It stops crashing the browser, and also returns the correct result!

Comment: That's a lot of fruit! What happens if you just publish the 10 most recent documents to the client instead of all 5k?

Comment: @DavidWeldon It stops crashing the browser, and also returns the correct result! What do you think happened? When querying for one document, why is publishing only a small number of documents different from publishing all the documents?

Comment: Did you check memory usage at that time. According to docs unlimited sort is done in-memory. Somehow your crash could be expected if you have limited resources. On the other side one sort which consumes up to 32 Mb is not much if it is the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm uncertain if meteor is continually trying to sort the documents as they are sent to the client (restarting every time a new one is sent), or if it blocks on the full result set before executing the sort. Either way, I strongly recommend against syncing thousands of documents to the client. As you illustrated in your example, it's resource intensive in both network and CPU.

Your goal should be to sync small subsets of the database on an as-needed basis. If you need to operate on a large dataset, I'd recommend using a method call (and possibly caching the results on the server).